# export mysql data to csv in php,don't print information in csv file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

when i take result , at that no table information, just exist table field name!
another problem this is, all information in one column.
this is my code :

```
 <?php 

if(isset($_POST['sub_csv'])){
    $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("school",$conn);

   $filename='uploads/'.strtotime("now").'.csv';

    $fp=fopen($filename,"w");

    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student");
    $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if($num_rows >=1)
    {
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

    $seperator="";
    $comma="";

    foreach($row as $name => $value)
    {
        $seperator .= $comma . '' .str_replace('','""',$name);
        $comma=",";
    }
    $seperator .="\n";
    fputs($fp,$seperator);
        fclose($fp);
    }

    else
    {
        echo 'No record in database';
    }
}
?>
```

result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR9UB.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use direct fputcsv() function to create csv file. Refer the below sample code and alter you php code. You will get you expected result.

```
// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3'));

// fetch the data
mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database');
$rows = mysql_query('SELECT field1,field2,field3 FROM table');

// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);
```

For more to read: 
1. http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/creating-downloadable-csv-files/
2. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: thanx , the new problem this is don't true show persian information in csv file.
I add this code before select query:

  

     mysql_query('set names "utf8"');

[result image][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WJZHy.png

Answer (score 0):

Now you only fetch the first row
`$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);`

You need to fetch all the rows one by one using a while loop like that `while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){..}`

Based on the code you provided:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['sub_csv'])){
    $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("school",$conn);

   $filename='uploads/'.strtotime("now").'.csv';

    $fp=fopen($filename,"w");

    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student");
    $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if($num_rows >=1)
    {
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){

    $seperator="";
    $comma="";

    foreach($row as $name => $value)
    {
        $seperator .= $comma . '' .str_replace('','""',$name);
        $comma=",";
    }
    $seperator .="\n";
    fputs($fp,$seperator);
    }
        fclose($fp);
    }

    else
    {
        echo 'No record in database';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanx , the new problem this is don't true show persian information in csv file. I add this code before select query: mysql_query('set names "utf8"'); [result image][1] [1]: i.stack.imgur.com/WJZHy.png